# Unable to Find the Control from codebehind, but able to find other controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I am able to find the controls of all of these Lables and TextBoxes accept the edateTB.  This is strange to me because it is in the same view as the sdateTB.  So why would edateTB return NULL when I try to use FindControl on it and sdateTB return the correct control?

Thanks in Advance, this one has been frustrating me for awhile.

Here is the codebehind where I am getting this error.  There is more code in this, but I just thought I would include everything up to the part where I get the NULL error.

```
 protected void ReservationDetail_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    TextBox idBox = (TextBox)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("tbID");
    int id = int.Parse(idBox.Text);
    Label specDays = (Label)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("DaysHdr");
    Label weekdays = (Label)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("WeekdaysHdr");
    ListBox dates = (ListBox)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("DatesList");
    Label days = (Label)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("WeekdaysLbl");
    Label sdate = (Label)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("startDateLbl");
    TextBox sdateTb= (TextBox)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("startDateTB");
    Label eDate = (Label)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("endDateLbl");
    TextBox edateTB = (TextBox)dvReservationDetail.FindControl("endDateTB");
}
```

Here is the Detailsview where the labels and Textboxes are.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvReservationDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDetail"
                    OnDataBound="ReservationDetail_DataBound" CssClass="detailgrid" GridLines="None"
                    DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateRows="false" Visible="false" Width="100%" OnItemUpdating="ReservationDetail_Updating">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' ReadOnly="true" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LabName" DataField="labName" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Class" DataField="class" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Class Size" DataField="classSize" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Software">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ListBox ID="software" Width="150" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Time">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="startTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("startTime") %>' />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Time">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="endTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("endTime") %>' />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="WeekdaysHdr" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Days Reserved By Week"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="DaysHdr" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Specific Days Reserved"></asp:Label>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ListBox ID="DatesList" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:ListBox>
                                <asp:Label ID="WeekdaysLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Weekday") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="startDateLbl" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="startDateTB" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Test"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="endDateLbl" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="End Date"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="endDateTB" runat="server" Visible="false" Text=""></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="repeatTypeTB" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("repeats") %>'></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <%-- <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />--%>
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>
```

Comment: this.dvReservationDetail?? "this" looks different to me. I hope you would have seen it. Is there on any purpose?

Comment: The _this_ is implied in the other lines that reference dsReservationDetail; removing it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was just playing around with putting it there to see if that would fix it.

Comment: May be it is Visible False and an Empty Text?

Comment: startDateTB also has Visible="False" and adding text into the endDateTB still made it return Null.  I am just trying to figure out why the startDateTB is fine but the endDateTB is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 ItemTemplate tags in your last TemplateField tag. Notice:

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <HeaderTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="endDateLbl" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="End Date"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="endDateTB" runat="server" Visible="false" Text=""></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="repeatTypeTB" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("repeats") %>'></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

It is possible that the first one that contains endDateTB is being ignored.

It should look like:

```
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <HeaderTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="endDateLbl" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="End Date"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="endDateTB" runat="server" Visible="false" Text=""></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField> 
<asp:TemplateField> 
    <HeaderTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="repeatTypeLbl" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Repeat"></asp:Label></HeaderTemplate> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="repeatTypeTB" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("repeats") %>'></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: +1 from me. I saw this and was about to post the same answer when my wife called me down to help feed our baby daughter!

Answer (score 0):

all the other lines are (label)dvreservationdetail...

the last line is (label)this.dvreservationdetail...

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's implied like Michael Todd said up in the comments.  I just put that there to see if it would fix it.